# How to create a form for updating a record using chronoforms?

Tags: php, joomla, chronoforms

I'm using chronoforms 5, made a form for creating a record. It works all fine.
But my problem is I need a form for edit the record. I've no idea how to load & show the record data. Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be able to identify the record you want to edit. Usually this is by the Record ID, the User ID, or possibly the User email if that is unique. Then you can make a copy of your entry form, rename it, and add a DB Read action at the top of the On Load event in the Setup tab - if you are using the Simple Wizard then you have to switch the form to Advanced mode in the General tab to do this.

Edit the DB Read action to link to the table and set the Conditions box to load the record you want to edit - there is a FAQ about doing that.

Comment: You did what exactly?

Comment: reading all values and setting them by javascript. a bit stupid way. is there any way? I've given up using chronoforms...

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ChronoConnection to list the records. The user selects a record which then displays the form to edit it.